# Limit points of a bounded infinite subset of a topological space

Tags: general-topology

If I have an infinite subset A of a topological space X, such that A is a subset of a basic set B, then A has at least one limit point.

Is this statement correct?

Comment: I answered you but you didn't react. Did you find my answer unsatisfying?

Comment: Yes, I didn't react because I already understood I was wrong. thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No that's not correct. Take any infinite set $X$ with the discrete topology. Let $B$ be any infinite proper subset of $X$ and $A$ an infinite subset of $B$. $A$ has no limit point. A limit point of $A$ is an element $a\in A$ such that any neighborhood of $a$ in $A$ contains another element of $A$, but that's not right as $\{a\}$ is a neighborhood of $a$ in $A$ that contains no other element of $A$.

Comment: That is not a counterexample because any base set is a singleton and there is no infinite set A that is a subset of a singleton.

Comment: @WilliamElliot: The "singleton" basis $\{\{x\} \,|\, x \in X\}$ is indeed a basis of the discrete topology, and this answer would indeed be incorrect if that were the only basis of the discrete topology. However, in general a topology has many different bases, and the discrete topology is no different in that regard. For instance, another basis of the discrete topology is the entire power set ${\cal{P}}X$, which is an appropriate choice for making this answer work.

Comment: @WilliamElliot Ah I didn't know that by "basic set" he meant a basis element (I thought an arbitrary set). Thank you for the clarification. But as Lee Mosher explained, the power set is itself a basis for the discrete topology (any topology is itself a basis for itself). Hence this is a valid counterexample.

Comment: @LeeMosher.  If the topology is a base, then there is no point to limit B to a base set;  it can be any open set.  The problem needs to clarify what is considered a base set.  As usually, there is no minimal base, what could he have intended by base set?

Comment: I agree that the problem needs to clarify what is considered a base set. That's why the answer of Scientifica is just fine: without any basis being specified, the OP has left the answerer free to give a counterexample, by choosing a particular topology and basis for that topology.

Answer (score 0):

NO. Let $X$ be an uncountable set with the co-countable topology: If $\phi \ne Y\subset X$ then $Y$ is open iff $X$ \ $Y$ is countable (i.e. finite or countably infinite).

Let $B$ be $any$ non-empty open subset of $X$ and let $A$ be a  countably infinite subset of $B.$ For any $p\in X$ the set $(X$ \ $A)\cup \{p\}$ is a nbhd of $p$ that contains no members of $A$ \ $\{p\}.$